# ASP.NET MVC using subclass in DisplayTemplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having issues getting my controller to recognize the subclass model on a postback.

I'm creating a dynamic web form with the field meta data stored in the db. For my ViewModels, I have a two parent types

```
public class Form
{
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
public class Question
{
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
}
```

and subclass of Question

```
public class TextBoxQuestion : Question
{
    public string TextAnswer { get; set; }
    public int TextBoxWidth { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a view that takes a Form type as the Model and two display templates, one for Question and one form TextBoxQuestion.

```
//Views/Form/index.cshtml
@model Form
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Questions)
```

-

```
//Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Question.cshtml
@model Question
@if(Model is TextBoxQuestion)
{
    @Html.DisplayForModel("TextBoxQuestion")
}
```

-

```
//Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/TextBoxQuestion.cshtml
@model TextBoxQuestion
<div>
    @Model.QuestionText
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TextAnswer)
</div>
```

When the page loads, my controller creates an instance of TextBoxQuestion, adds it to the Question collection and passes the Form object to the view. Everything works find and the textbox appears on the page.

But when I postback to the controller, the code doesn't recognize the question as a TextBoxQuestion. It only sees it as the parent type Question.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Form f)
{
    foreach (var q in f.Questions)
    {
        if (q is TextBoxQuestion)
        {
            //code never gets here
        }
        else if (q is Form)
        {
            //gets here instead
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm not sure if creating a Question.cshtml will work.  Try putting the same code into Object.cshtml template instead.  It's my understanding the templates only work for native types i.e. String etc

Comment: Just a note, I discovered with the code above, the Question DisplayTemplate will be bypassed by the framework. It recognizes the subtype and will use that DisplayTemplate instead. I had to explicitly define the template name in @Html.DisplayFor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model binder will create an instance of the type the method is expecting. If you want to use subclasses and display templates this way you will need to write your own model binder.

I would suggest to check for existence of one or several attributes to determine whether a `TextBoxQuestion` or `Question` is being posted.

Modelbinder:

```
public class QuestionModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Question result;
        ValueProviderResult text = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("TextAnswer");
        if (text != null) // TextAnswer was submitted, we'll asume the user wants to create a TextBoxAnswer
            result = new TextBoxQuestion { TextAnswer = text.AttemptedValue /* Other attributes */ };
        else
            result = new Question();

        // Set base class attributes
        result.QuestionText = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("QuestionText").AttemptedValue;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then hook it up in Global.asax.cs:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Question), new QuestionModelBinder());
```

Comment: Thanks strmstn. Did more digging and you're right about the binder creating an object defined by the Action parameter. I was hoping the framework was smart enough to infer the type at runtime. :(

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're just asking one question at a time. So when you post your info most likeley you are only sending one and not a collection of Questions.  Change your Method to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Question q)
{
    if (q is TextBoxQuestion)
    {
        //proces TextBoxQuestion
    }
    else if (q is Question)
    {
        //process generic question
    }
}
```

Comment: I failed to mention the Form model I'm passing to the View has a collection of Questions. So there will be more than one question posted back. To simplify the issue, I'm only working with one question for now.

Comment: Will the ASP.NET MVC model binder really pass a TextBoxQuestion if the method is expecting a Question?